# Thick and light walled dots sequence

Tags: logical-deduction, sequence

Hi I saw this sequence and cant's stop thinking about it.

[image: sequence]

I was guessing that the number of thick-walled dots represents the number of sides for the next shape in the sequence

the 3rd shape has 3 thick-walled dots, and the 4th has 3 sides

the 4th has 6 dots, and the 5th could be said to have 6 sides (though that's a stretch.....)

and maybe a rounded box is considered to have 0 sides?

It just seems that there must be a better explanation, and maybe a whole different answer.

**EDIT**

I had a new idea, that still feels like a stretch

> The solution would be the second figure if we dismiss any relationship between the number of dots and just focus of the shape that the thick-walled dots create. 
>  the 4th makes a rectangle and the next figure is a rectangle. the 3rd makes a triangle and the next figure is a triangle. the 2nd of the options makes some weird shape that might resemble the 3rd, and here starts the stretch I was talking about. finally the 1st does not have a shape with means the next should not have side defined shape and since it has no corners it does not have a side.

Comment: Where's it from? (An IQ test of some sort? A puzzle hunt somewhere?)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan My GF took a test for a company while applying for a position. She did not know the answer and juts choose randomly and sent me a picture.

Comment: Some tests like this do not have a specific solution, but a (more or less) consistent _explanation_ to a proposed solution is the key part then.

Comment: Hm, your explanation would be more consistent when you talked about "corners" instead of "sides". However, I do not see how the fifth figure could be interpreted having 6 sides (or corners)

Comment: Some shapes look like they have thicker borders. This could be relevant.

Comment: It could be that having more dark circles than light ones means the next shape has a thick border, but that’s not saying much by itself when you have two relationships to go on.

Comment: Is there somewhere an image of better quality? The "thickness of lnes" comes not out very well. In the bottom row: Are the shapes 1 and 4 supposed to have a "thick" outlines and the others not?  Is the left side of the fifth top-row symbol's boxes thick?

Comment: My current thinking goes towards symmetry axes instead of counting - both for the outer shape and the circles (separately), but I've not yet found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that

> the thick-walled dots may represent the shape of the following figure.
>  That would mean, that number 2 is the solution, but it has one dot at
>  the top that does not fit the shape.

I then tried to find a pattern in the numbers, but I wasn't able to find one. But here are the numbers (I wasn't able to make it a spoiler):

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| figure | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| sides | 4 | ? | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| “white" dots | 25 | ? | 7 | 3 | 1 |
| “black" dots | 0 | ? | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| dots | 25 | ? | 10 | 9 | 10 |

I could not get to a solution, but maybe someone can use my work...

A search on OEIS

> for patterns in the white dots concluded that there are only number sequences for `1, 3, 7, 15, 25` and none if swapping the 15 with 18 or 22. This leaves the fourth figure as the answer. [Link to OEIS search.](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C7%2C15%2C25&sort=&go=Suche)

Comment: I did a similar breakdown. Only pattern I could see was that the "black" dots can be made to follow a fibonacci-esque pattern with a 3 in the blank.

Comment: Thought about the same thing, that would only leave figure 1, 3 or 5 as the solution. I also thought the "white" dots could be substracted by 10, 8, 4, 2, forming a `-2 /2`pattern, but that is a bit of a stretch and would leave figure 4 as the solution

Comment: @Alconja I added something, but that clashes with your fibonacci approach. You can find `0, 6, 3, 6, 9` in several decimal expansions, but that is a veeeery big stretch.